# How to access angular module in protractor E2E test spec

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-fullstack

I am using the [angular fullstack yeoman generator](https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack) and I am trying to access a service to register a new instance of a controller providing the scope object in my protractor e2e spec. I am trying:

```
describe('Testing Controllers', function () {
  var rootScope;
  var scope;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope) {
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));
```

I am getting `Error: TypeError: module is not a function`. Why does my spec not have access to the angular module?

Comment: The thing you're writing is unit test, not e2e. And you should run unit tests with Karma, not Protractor.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I was reading AngularJS Testing Cookbook (Bailey, Simon) where he is accessing scope via protractor, thats what got me on this path. Is there a compelling reason not to watch for scope changes in E2E tests?

Comment: Because e2e are supposed to test behaviour (the way the app affects DOM), not units (which services and controllers are). If you need to strengthen your tests with scope assertions, you can get scope objects them from DOM like `angular.element(node).scope()` and `angular.element(node).isolateScope()`